# echo inside if loop

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a variable like this

```
$string = "0>0.1";
```

I want to evaluate this inside an if loop like this

```
if($string)
{
  ///something
}
```

but im getting an error if i am doing this. How to go about it

Comment: Which error? I even dont know, what this code snippet should do (a non-empty string is always evaluated to `true` here).

Comment: Hey guys, @Deepak is asking genuine question, he want to use eval.

Comment: i am getting error when i try this if(echo $string)

Answer (score 1):

you do not understand how evaluations or strings work.
If you put anything in a string, it will not be evaluated, but simply contain that value from that moment on.

```
$string = "0>0.1"; // contains "0>0.1"

$bool = 0>0.1; // contains TRUE
```

The IF statement needs a boolean, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) to evaluate things in strings. Remember that `eval` is evil and any php code may be in it.

Comment: +1 
perhaps to illustrate your point better : 
If $string in your example came from a POST or GET, an evil user could enter PHP code in the POST or GET variable, which would be executed at the moment `eval` was executed.

Answer (score 0):

You got some awful advise with your duplicate. Here is a safer eval variant that will actually evaluate to an result:

```
$str = "0>0.1";
if (preg_replace('/^(\d+\.?\d*)([><])(\d+\.?\d*)$/e', "$1 $2 $3", $str))
{
```

Note that it would still return true for invalid strings like `"1>2b"`. You would need a match and a separate expression evaluation for that. (Writing a faux mini parser here isn't difficult, but obviously overkill for your question.)