# php echo inside if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [echo inside if loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663128/echo-inside-if-loop)

I am trying to evaluate strings like
"0>0.1","0<0.2" etc.
suppose $string = "0>0.1" and i write if($string) it is always evaluating it to true since it is a non-empty string
so i tried this way
if(echo $string)
and this time i am getting an error saying that i cannot echo inside if

Comment: where are these strings come from?

Comment: Programming doesn't work that way.

Comment: echo is a language construct, not a function. It doesn't return anything when it finishes.

Comment: You imply that no language construct returns anything when it finishes which is untrue.

Comment: the strings are coming from a loop inside which these statements lie. There are no user inputs here

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the eval() function.

```
if ( eval( $string ) ) {
}
```

http://php.net/eval

Comment: but this again gives me a error like this

Comment: @Deepak read the manual page. Your strings are not ready to be used in eval. There are several things you must do (like add semicolons where appropriate, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Of course, this is very, very dangerous, so use it with caution.

Comment: i would suggest to avoid eval as much as possible

Comment: @Shakti you're right, but if the OP wants to use it, she'll use it. The manual page I linked to explains the risks thoroughly.

Comment: Did anyone even test this out?  `eval` on those strings won't even work!

Comment: @tandu that's why the user needs to read the manual page.