# conditional statements as strings

Tags: php, algorithm, trading, algorithmic-trading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [echo inside if loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663128/echo-inside-if-loop)

I trying to code a trading system and i have a list of entry and exit strategies. To lessen the number of lines in the code I planned to put all my strategies into an array for each entry and exit. My array is like this

```
$enter_strats = array(
   array('name'=>"macd",'strat'=>"/$divergence[/$key]>0.1;"),
);
```

I am including the conditional statements inside the array as above.
while I am looping thru everyday prices, I have to check for each entry strategy if they they are true. My if statement is like this

```
foreach($divergence as $key=>$value)
{
    if($trade ==0)
    {
        foreach($enter_strats as $k =>$v)
        {
            $strat = $v['strat'];
            $strat = str_replace("#","$",$strat);
            eval("\$strat = \"$strat\";");
            if ($strat)
            {
                $trade =1;
                $book->save($key,$close[$key],$v['name']);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

The problem since it is  a string its always if is always evaluating it to true. I tried to put one more eval inside if but its of no use.

Please help to solve this problem, its is very essential. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please consider to accept some answers. and please use `{}` button on text-editor to format code.

Comment: Hmz, can you give some more example of strats? I have an idea on how to create that array, just wanna see how feasible it is.

Comment: This was not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663128/echo-inside-if-loop. If this question was reason for closing as "exact duplicate" the question should be reopened. In the referenced question, there's an attempt to use an uninterpreted string as conditional whereas here the author has tried to call eval().

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're trying to lessen the number of lines in the code.

## Arrays intended to keep data, not code.

As soon as you understand it, your code will be okay.

'strat' should contain only data. An operator and a number for instance.
keeping variable name in the string makes no sense.
especially if you have this variable already.
You have already have $divergence[$key] in your code.

So, 'strat' should be just `array('>',0.1)`