# Php calculator printing out numbers instead of result

Tags: php

My php is printing out the numbers instead of the result. Example, it'll print out "3+3" instead of "6".

What am i doing wrong? Can someone explains how php reads the code and how i can fix it. 
- new beginner learning php

```
        <?php

            //Check to see if the submit button got posted
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                //If it did, get the values from the textbox
                $first_number = $_POST['first_number'];
                $second_number= $_POST['second_number'];
                $operator = $_POST['operator'];

                //Check to see if they are empty
                if(!empty($first_number) && !empty($second_number)){

                    echo $first_number . $operator . $second_number;

                    }

                else {
                    echo 'Please fill out all the forms';
                }

            }

        ?>
 </head>
    <body>

        <div id='wrap'> 


            <header id='header'>
                <h1> This Is A Simple Math Calculator </h1>
            </header>

            <section id='main'>
                <form action='math.php' method='POST'>
                <table cellspacing='10px'>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type='text' name='first_number' placeholder='First Number'  size='15px'/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name='operator'>
                                <option value='+'>+</option>
                                <option value='-'>-</option>
                                <option value='*'>*</option>
                                <option value='/'>/</option>
                                <option value='%'>%</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='second_number' placeholder='Second Number' size='15px' />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='=' />
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <input type='text' name='answer' placeholder='' size='10px' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </section>

            <footer>
                <p> MADE BY @KD </p>
            </footer>
```

Comment: This question was ask many times before! Please search in google or on stackoverflow!

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate math expression from a string using eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Comment: You're the one echoing out `$first_number` appended with the string `$operator` appended with the string `$second_number`. No calculations are taking place here - you're just outputting the values.

Comment: A string with code is not code. I'd dare say that applies to most programming languages, not just PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, you can build it like this

```
  if($operator == "+"){
     echo $first_number + $second_number;
  }
  if($operator == "-"){
     echo $first_number - $second_number;
  }

  // same for other operators you permit.
```

Comment: I think this is the better way of doing math and a lot safer.

Comment: I actually edited my comment before you posted yours ;-)

Answer (score -1):

change

```
echo $first_number . $operator . $second_number;
```

to

```
echo eval("echo $first_number$operator$second_number ;");
```

Comment: NEVER use `eval()`! It's bad.

Comment: we can use type casting etc to make it secure

Answer (score -2):

```
echo $result = eval('return '.$first_number . $operator . $second_number.';');
```

Comment: NEVER use `eval()`! It's bad.

Comment: `POST page.php - second_number=; system('sudo rm rf /')`. Goodbye server. Now all the files are deleted, and I can thank `eval()` for this awesome exploit. Thank you `eval()`!