# Calculate the total sum for each category from a text file

Tags: php, file, text, sum, file-get-contents

I have a text file there I store all the data like this:

```
dept|test-1|365|0
dept|test-2|134|0
expense|test-3|4387|0
expense|test-4|105|0
```

How can I get the sum of each category for all the transaction within that category?

In this example, the category `dept` will have a total sum of `499` and the category `expense` will have a total sum of `4'492`.

But how can I do this within PHP?

Here's my current code:

```
function do_maths($expression) {
    eval('$o = ' . preg_replace('/[^0-9\+\-\*\/\(\)\.]/', '', $expression) . ';');
    return $o;
}

function inifile($fname, $word) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($fname.'.ini');
    $pattern = preg_quote($word, '/');
    $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
        sort($matches[0]);

        # TABELL
        echo '<div class="table">';

            # LOOP
            foreach($matches[0] AS $found) {
                $transaction = explode('|', $found);

                echo '<div class="table-row'.($transaction[3] == 1 ? ' color-grey-light" title="'.$transaction[1].' är betalad"' : '"').'>';
                    echo '<div class="table-cell-left table-cell-left-width">';
                        echo $transaction[1];
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="table-cell-right">';
                        echo '<span class="sum">';
                            echo do_maths($transaction[2]);
                        echo '</span> kr';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }

        echo '</div>';


    } else {
        echo '<div class="message color-blue">';
            echo 'Kunde inte hitta något';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: do you have code where you are currently opening/reading the text file?

Comment: I have added the entire code in my question :) Sorry for the confusion. I guess I'm getting tired -.- The clock is 00:47 here now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First read your text file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). Then go through each array element(each line of your text file) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) it by `|` as delimiter.

So your array will change from (Array at point 1):

```
Array
(
    [0] => dept|test-1|365|0
    [1] => dept|test-2|134|0
    [2] => expense|test-3|4387|0
    [3] => expense|test-4|105|0
)
```

to (Array at point 2):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => dept
            [1] => test-1
            [2] => 365
            [3] => 0
        )
    //...
)
```

After this you can loop through your `$lines` array and use the category (first array element of the subArray) as index and add the value (third array element) to the array.

Then you can call [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) for each category subArray with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

So you sum all values together for each category. So your array (Array at point 3):

```
Array
(
    [dept] => Array
        (
            [0] => 365
            [1] => 134
        )

    [expense] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4387
            [1] => 105
        )

)
```

Will become like this (Array at point 4):

```
Array
(
    [dept] => 499
    [expense] => 4492
)
```

And at the end just loop through your array and display your data:

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);  //Array at point 1
    $lines = array_map(function($v){
        return explode("|", $v);
    }, $lines);  //Array at point 2

    foreach($lines as $line)
        $data[$line[0]][] = $line[2];
    //Array at point 3  
    $result = array_map("array_sum", $data); 
    //Array at point 4
    foreach($result as $category => $sum)
        echo $category . " = " . $sum . "<br>";

?>
```

output:

```
dept = 499
expense = 4492
```

**EDIT:**

So my code implemented into your function will look something like this:

```
<?php

    function getCategoryFromFile($fileName, $category) {
        $lines = file($fileName, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

        $lines = array_map(function($v){
            return explode("|", $v);
        }, $lines);

        $keys = array_keys(array_column($lines, 0), $category);


        if(!empty($keys)) {

            echo '<div class="table">';

            foreach($keys as $key) {

                echo '<div class="table-row' . ($lines[$key][3] == 1 ? ' color-grey-light" title="' . $lines[$key][1] . ' är betalad"' : '"') . '>';
                    echo '<div class="table-cell-left table-cell-left-width">';
                        echo $lines[$key][1];
                    echo '</div>';                      
                echo '</div>';

            }

            echo '<div class="table-cell-right">';
                echo '<span class="sum">';
                    echo array_sum(array_column(array_intersect_key($lines, array_flip($keys)), 2));
                echo '</span> kr';
            echo '</div>';

            echo '</div>';

        } else {
            echo '<div class="message color-blue">';
                echo 'Kunde inte hitta något';
            echo '</div>';
        }

    }

    //As example
    getCategoryFromFile("test.txt", "expense");

?>
```

The first part is the same as in my code above. But to now only loop through the data of the category which you want we need the keys to these subArrays. Which we get with this line:

```
$keys = array_keys(array_column($lines, 0), $category);
```

So basically we grab all categories from your array with `array_column($lines, 0)`, which will return an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dept
    [1] => dept
    [2] => expense
    [3] => expense
)
```

Then with [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and `$category` we only get the keys of this array from the category which you want. Which for example for `expense` will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

Then we just check if we have some keys, means some lines with the category which you want. If yes we loop through these keys and use them to access the data, which you want.

After the foreach loop to print the sum of the values we use this line:

```
echo array_sum(array_column(array_intersect_key($lines, array_flip($keys)), 2));
```

But let's break it a bit down. First we have:

```
array_intersect_key($lines, array_flip($keys))
```

Where we grab the key intersect of these two arrays with [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php). On the left side we have the array `$lines` as first array which as we know looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => dept
            [1] => test-1
            [2] => 365
            [3] => 0
        )
    //...
)
```

Now on the other side as second array we have the keys from the category which we want, so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
)
```

And then the result/intersect will be (Note: Since we grab the intersect of they keys, we have to flip `$keys` with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)):

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => expense
            [1] => test-3
            [2] => 4387
            [3] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => expense
            [1] => test-4
            [2] => 105
            [3] => 0
        )

)
```

Out of this array we get the second column from each subArray with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). So from the above array we will end up with:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4387
    [1] => 105
)
```

And then finally we get the sum of this array with `array_sum()` and you will get:

```
4492
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! But how can I put your code in my code? I'm sitting here with a big question mark above my head and have done so during the past 7 minutes.

Comment: @ErikEdgren 1) So first of, since my first post I added a few more details to my answer, I hope this helps to understand my code even better and you know what's going on 2) For your `do_maths()` function I can recommend you to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18880772/3933332 3) I don't really see through your `inifile()` function , what it should do? What do you want to do with your pattern? And also why do you get the content of a `.ini` file, if we are talking about a text file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 1) I have read your last edit in your answer but I think I'm to tired to understand half of it. 2) Thank you for the link. I will read it 3) My `inifile()` function searches for the category you have typed in for `$word` and prints all the transaction for that category

Comment: @ErikEdgren ( 1) If you don't understand it and get stuck, sleep first and then take a new look) 2) Now I see what it should do. Only I don't understand why `*.ini` ? I thought we are talking about a text file?!

Comment: 1) Yeah. I will do that :) 2) Sweet! :) `ini` files are basically text files but are mainly for configurations (as if you didn't already know that :P). The extension is just something I chose to have for now. I will change it sometime :)

Comment: @ErikEdgren So I think I figured it out what you want: http://pastebin.com/eSxp64x5 <- Let me know if this is what you need of if not what is wrong

Comment: @ErikEdgren Had an error in the pastebin code. Just reload this page and click on the new link in the above comment

Comment: The loop part to print every transaction for the category of choice are already fixed in my code. The only thing I want, is to get the total sum of all the transaction to print it below the loop, which you have succeeded with in your answer but I don't know how to get your code into mine code :) Maybe because I'm to tired

Comment: @ErikEdgren You're welcome. Give me a minute an I will add an edit to my answer.

Comment: @ErikEdgren updated my answer to explain a bit more, how I changed your code. Hope it helps for your understanding.