# Alternatives to eval() for doing math equations using php

Tags: php, math, eval, user-input

Are there alternative to using eval() for doing math equations, or is there some way to safety use eval with user inputs?

```
$string = "1+2-3*4/5";
$answer = eval($answer = $string);
```

Comment: Validate the input before computing it. See some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18880772/3933332

Comment: or using some [parser](https://github.com/ircmaxell/php-math-parser/tree/master/lib/PHPMathParser)

Comment: I already wrote that under your last question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to only select the mathematical and numericals from the given string, then do the eval.

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9()+\-*\/.]/", $string, $output_array);
$operation = implode("", $output_array[0]);
eval($operation);
```