# Eval is discouraged in php 7

Tags: eval, php-7

I am getting formula in string foe example

```
$a = '1*2*(2+3)';
echo eval($a) // Output should be 10
```

Now i am trying to evaluate this string and use eval for that but in php 7 give me this error Use of eval() is discouraged so how can i evaluate this string.

Answer (score 6):

[**PHP *never* raises any such error**](http://lxr.php.net/search?q=discouraged&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&type=&project=PHP-7.0): You should be suspicious that a third party has interfered with the installation, possibly installed some kind of "security" focused extension that changes the behaviour of PHP.

All such extensions are not sanctioned by the PHP project, and are terrible.

Despite what the manual says about eval, there is [no technical difference](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP-7.1/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#5458) between including a file, and evaling some code.

The only difference in the real world is that eval'd code may contain user input: The sanitization and filtering of user input is a problem for PHP applications that do not use eval.

*Note: you are missing a return from the evaluated expression*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `echo` on `eval()` unless you use `return` in the evaluated code.

> `eval()` returns `NULL` unless `return` is called in the evaluated code

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

So you can do:

```php
$a = 'echo 1*2*(2+3);';
eval($a);
```

or

```php
$a = 'return 1*2*(2+3);';
echo eval($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) says;

> **Caution**
>
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

As far as the alternative is concerned you can try this solution given in the thread: [calculate math expression from a string using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)