# php calculate string values: "2+4+3-12+3-5"

Tags: php, string, calculator

How can I calculate values in a string containing the following numbers and (+/-) operators:

Code Like

```
$string = "3+5+3-7+4-3-1"; 

//result should be = 4
```

**Updated:**
I am trying to calculate $array = [1, +, 6, -, 43, +, 10];

I have converted into the string: implode("", $array);

Comment: how is that supposed to be 4? what is your mathematical logic? There should be brackets used here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Could you enlighten me, please? Why brackets?

Comment: @kerbholz My mistake; caffeine hasn't kicked in yet ;-) *heh*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Ok ;)

Comment: @ Ehtasham: Remove the quotes. @kerbholz *cheers* :)

Comment: https://eval.in/988181 < no quotes.

Comment: I reopened the question; that "possible" duplicate, wasn't one of that at all.

Comment: seeing the edit now; this question is starting to look unclear and a possible rabbit hole. I voted to close as such; unclear.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval

Comment: vote to close as unclear. First OP was talking about summing a string, now its an array?

Comment: I have just try to clarify why string like above.

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale I know, lovely huh? Same vote to close. Well, I'm out of this one. See if anyone else can make "heads or tails" out of what they really want (now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For any kind of array like: [1, + , 4, -, 5, , 3, 8, + , 6]**

Solved with the custom php helper function:

```
function calcArray($arrVal) 
{
    if (count($arrVal) == 1) {
        return reset($arrVal);
    }

    if (is_int($arrVal[1])) {
        $arrVal[0] = $arrVal[0].$arrVal[1];

        unset($arrVal[1]);

        return calcArray(array_values($arrVal)); 
    }

    $emptyValKey = array_search('', $arrVal);

    if ($emptyValKey) {
        $concatVal = $arrVal[$emptyValKey-1].$arrVal[$emptyValKey+1];

        unset($arrVal[$emptyValKey+1]);
        unset($arrVal[$emptyValKey]);

        $arrVal[$emptyValKey-1] = $concatVal;

        return calcArray(array_values($arrVal));
    }

    $total = $arrVal[1] == "+" ? $arrVal[0] + $arrVal[2]:$arrVal[0] - $arrVal[2];

    unset($arrVal[0]);
    unset($arrVal[1]);
    unset($arrVal[2]);

    array_unshift($arrVal, $total);

    $arrVal = array_values(array_filter($arrVal));

    return calcArray($arrVal);
}
```

Comment: It can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
$string = "3+5+3-7+4-3-1"; 
eval( '$res = (' . $string . ');' );
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr_val = array(1, '+', 6, '-', 43, '+', 10);
$total = 0;

if(isset($arr_val[0]) && ($arr_val[0] != '+' || $arr_val[0] != '-'))
    $total = intval($arr_val[0]);

foreach($arr_val AS $key => $val) {
    if($val == '+') {
        if(isset($arr_val[$key+1]) && ($arr_val[$key+1] != '+' || $arr_val[$key+1] != '-')) {
            $total = $total + intval($arr_val[$key+1]);
        }
    } else if($val == '-') {
        if(isset($arr_val[$key+1]) && ($arr_val[$key+1] != '+' || $arr_val[$key+1] != '-')) {
            $total = $total - intval($arr_val[$key+1]);
        }
    }
}

echo $total;
```

May be it will solve your problem.