# Convert string expression in operation in php

Tags: php, string, int, expression, operation

If i've a string like this

```
((((((4,50*0,86)*52500*1,0016)+3800)/52500)*2,2046)*1,05)
```

how can i do the operation for obtaning the total result?

Thank You

Comment: Be very careful using user input with eval though

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a string?

Comment: @Devon This is true, NEVER eval a user input, but the accepted answer in that question has a split solution, that he can use.

Comment: @Peon, that split solution only looks to work with a very basic math expression, not what the OP has provided, but there are other answers there that attempt to sanitize.

Comment: Solve with this solution! https://stackoverflow.com/a/27077376/3684020 Thank u

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your question is a possible duplicate from [calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

However

if you need to store this in a variable you can do

```
$string='((((((4,50*0,86)*52500*1,0016)+3800)/52500)*2,2046)*1,05)';
$response=eval('return '.str_replace(',','.',$string.';'));

print($response);
```

the output is:

```
9.14027512736
```