# php value math Equation when echo

Tags: php

I am trying to write a math equation with PHP

```
$text = "value1 * 2";

$txt = str_replace('value1','500',$text);
```

when echo $txt; // (500 * 2)

i want replace and equation and when echo // `1000`

thanks and regrades

Comment: It is string, you can use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) to run it as code but is not good idea

Comment: Also use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a variable with the value instead of using `str_replace()`?
It's way more readable and it's the correct way to do mathematical operations.

Like this:

```
$value1 = 500; 
$txt = $value1 * 2;
```

Note that this way the value you use in `$value1` could also be "500" because when doing `$value1 * 2` php converts it to a number

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using `explode` and `list`

```
$text = "value1 * 2";
$txt = str_replace('value1','500',$text);
list($string1, $string2) = explode("*", $txt);
echo $string1*$string2;
```