# I want to convert the text to numbers to get a mathematical result

Tags: php, math

echo $equation = "(5+10)-8+2*2";

echo $equation //outputs (5+10)-8+2*2

I want to show this result  11

Comment: Uuse `eval` on the string and the result would be the mathematical result.

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  because `echo $equation = "(5+10)-8+2*2";` will not even assign a value to `$equation`.... 

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculate math expression from a string using eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880772/calculate-math-expression-from-a-string-using-eval)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
echo eval($equation);
```